# Encontrar un elemento dentro de un slice que tiene varias rutas

Tags: go

Tengo el siguiente código dentro de este slice tengo una serie de rutas

```
 data[
 c\fdddd\pdf
 c\fdddd\sss.cd
 c\fdddd\sss.as
 ]
```

Con esta función intento saber si alguna ruta tiene algo que necesito

```
func CheckSlide(cont []string, find string) bool {
for _, findCont := range cont {
    if findCont == find {
        return true
    }
 }
 return false
}

 func main(){
 f := "PDF"
pdf := CheckSlide(data, f)
}
```

Pero me retorna `false`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Estás tratando de buscar una cadena en mayúsculas sobre un conjunto de cadenas en minúsculas con lo que no va a encontrarla.

Además, la comparación `findCont == find` la haces sobre la cadena completa respecto a un subconjunto de la misma con lo que tampoco puede haber coincidencia.

La manera más fácil es usar las funciones proporcionadas por el paquete `strings` de la biblioteca estándar para, en primer lugar, convertir las cadenas a minúsculas para asegurarte que todas son del mismo tipo y entonces buscar si la cadena de la lista contiene la que buscas.

```golang
func CheckSlide(cont []string, find string) bool {
    for _, findCont := range cont {
        if strings.Contains(strings.ToLower(findCont),  strings.ToLower(find) ) {
            return true
        }
    }
    return false
}
```

De todos modos esto te daría coincidencia con **cualquier** cadena (p.e. "c\nopdfs\txt") ya que solamente busca la existencia de la subcadena.

Comment: muchisimas gracias.. era justamente lo que necesitaba